# Flat Points in Irreducible Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, kakeya-sets

I am trying to understand the paper "Algebraic Methods in Discrete Analogs of the Kakeya Problem" by L. Guth and N. H. Katz.  This paper contains the following lemma:

Let $S$ be the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ on which the polynomial $p$ vanishes, and let $a$ be a regular point of $S$.  Suppose that $S$ contains 3 distinct lines all of which intersect at $a$.  Then $a$ is a flat point.

I'm having a hard time picturing the situation in this lemma.  Can someone give me examples (other than a plane) of irreducible algebraic varieties that contain three distinct lines that meet at a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ X = V(z^2-x^2-y^2)$, known as a cone. (See the picture.) However, for any point $p \in X$ other than $0$ there is only one line going through $p$ and contained in $X$.

[image: Cone]

Indeed, the plane is the only *surface* which contains three lines going through each of its points. 
In higher dimensions, there are more varieties with this property. (For example, you can consider the product $X \times \mathbb{A}^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}$ for an arbitrary $X$.)

If you want a nonsingular example, consider the surface $X$ defined by $z = xy(x-y)$. You probably can't visualise this, but algebraically it is easy to see that there are three lines on $X$ going through $0$. They are the lines defined by $z = x = 0$, $z = y = 0$ and $z = x-y = 0$.

Let me explain how I came up with this example. First, let us look at the "saddle surface" $S = V(z - xy)$. You have probably already seen $S$ at some point. If not, I hope you can find a good picture online somewhere, or maybe visualise it yourself. The point is, that contained in $S$ we find the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis. The reason is that, when we look at $S$ only in the xy-plane which is defined by $z = 0$ the defining equation reduces to $xy = 0$, which corresponds to the two coordinate axes. Now when we want to have three lines on our surface, we can just start with the equation $xy(x-y) = 0$, which describes the coordinate axes and a diagonal line, and then add a parameter $z$ to get $V(xy(x-y) - z) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

If we push this trick further, we can get an arbitrary number of lines in our surface, and I guess it starts looking like this:

[image: Saddle surface]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This is an enlightening example.  Do you know of any examples where the point is non-critical in the sense that the gradient of the polynomial is nonzero there?

Comment: @user121096: sorry, I completely overlooked that condition in your question. I have updated my answer accordingly.